# Malloc not printing correctly?

Tags: c, file-io, malloc

I have a .txt file that I am using to learn some basic C.

Here is the txt file:

```
8
12  48  15  65  16  82  9   72
```

Here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){

        int num;
        int arr[100000];
        int index = 0;
        int size = 0;

        if (argc != 2){
                return 0;
        }

        FILE *inputFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        if (inputFile == NULL){
                printf("Error1\n");
                return 0;
        }

/*      while(!feof(inputFile)){
                num = fgetc(inputFile);
                if(isdigit(num)){
                        num = num - '0';=
                        printf("%c\n",num);
                }
        }*/

        while(fscanf(inputFile, " %d", &num) == 1){
                arr[index] = num;
                index++;
        }

        size = arr[0];
        int * list = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
        int i;

        for(i = 1; i <= size; i++){
                list[i-1]=arr[i];
                printf("%d\n", list[i]);
        }




        if(!feof(inputFile)){
                printf("error");
                return 0;
        }

}
```

I am looking to malloc the array, but I keep getting an output of 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ..... what is going wrong? I think maybe my print statement is wrong, but I am new to C.. any tips?

Comment: This is because you are setting `list[i-1]` but printing `list[i]`. Voting to close as a typo (you can delete your question if the comments provide an acceptable answer, too).

Comment: Good job for correctly using fscanf and feof

Answer (score 0):

You have 9 items, not 8

```
    size = arr[0];
    //printf("size %d %d\n", size,index);
    int * list = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(index));
    int i;

    for(i = 1; i <= index; i++){
            list[i-1]=arr[i-1];
            printf("%d\n", list[i-1]);
    }
```